# C++ Switching lines off and on

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, ide

I am using VS2010 C++.

For debugging reasons I have commented out lines like this:

```
ms+=t.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();
```

became

```
//timer:ms+=t.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();
```

Now when I want to include all timer lines, I do a simply text replace and replace all "//timer:" with an empty string, and all these lines become active again.
But there is no way to include the "//timer:" on all lines again.

I could use

```
#ifdef _MYVAR
         ms+=t.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();
#endif
```

instead, but that would make my code much less readable.

Is there a simply solution for my problem, for example a switch that I put in front of each line to activate or deactive the lines?

Comment: Does `assert` satisfy? (which will not be available in release build mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/*timer*/ // ms+=t.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();
```

Now you can search and replace `"/*timer*/ //"` with `"/*timer*/"`.  Then later, search and replace `"/*timer*/"` with `"/*timer*/ //"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex search (Regular Expressions), if you want the code to be more readable.

you can use a line like this

```
ms+=t.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec(); //TIMER
```

and search for `(.*) \/\/TIMER`
and replace with `//($1) //TIMER`

and for removal search for `//(.*) \/\/TIMER` and replace with `($1) //TIMER`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the syntax of the replacement RegEx.